# Transparent QWidget overlay on gstreamer- video

Tags: qt, overlay, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am using gstreamer-1.0 and overlaying a video stream on a QVideoWidget in Qt . I want to add transparent label to show on the video . The problem is that when I add the label to the layout , of the widget I render the video on , and keep updating the label continuously  it either:
- appears , but its background is the background of the window on which the video is rendered . I mean that the video is no longer rendered in the background of the label. (this is when label is updated faster than video frame rate) 
-label doesn't appear and all that I have is the video  (if label update rate is less than frame rate )

I tried adding a transparent widget to the video layout and adding the label to the new window but this also failed .

Here is my code

```
//  videoWindow                  //this is the window on which video is rendered
layTimer=new QGridLayout();  
dummyWidget=new QWidget();
timerLabel=new QLabel(dummyWidget);
videoWindow->setLayout(layTimer);
dummyWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
dummyWidget->setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
timerLabel()->setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
timerLabel()->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint );
dummyWidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint );
timerLabel()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
layTimer->addWidget(dummyWidget);
```

How can I solve this ? How can I display only text of the label on the video ?